# How to detect a fingerprint reader in Android Samsung Galaxy Note 4?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, samsung-galaxy

I'm trying to add FP authentication to my app, and for some reason it doesn't work on Note 4, while it does work fine on another Samsung devices (e.g. Galaxy S7) as well as on Nexus devices.
I do have Marshmallow 6.0.1 installed on that Note 4. Here are the two ways I tried to detect the FP reader:

Approach #1:

`FingerprintManager mFingerprintManager = context.getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class);
return mFingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()
             && mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints();`

Approach #2:

`return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT);`

Both return FALSE.

Note that I have other apps that use the FP reader on this device no problem. Is there another FP API I can leverage if the above returns False? I would use it as a fallback.

Comment: where is context come from ? Are your mFingerprintManager !=null ?

Comment: The context is coming from getActivity() and m.FingerprintManager is not null. The method call to detect the device and the enrolled fingers comes back as False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung S5 and Note 4 are not compatible with Android's Fingerscan APIs. It always returns **false** for **FingerprintManger.isHardwareDetected()**. Where as it works well on S6, S6Edge,S7 and S7Edge.